# Add an element in a Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

I have to implement the following method for my programming course:

The signature is `public void filmHinzufuegen(Film film)`:  If the film is not already in the "films" list, then add it to it. Otherwise do nothing. In case of errors (e.g. NullPointerException) nothing should happen.

So my idea was to implement it so, which is false:
Has anybody have any suggestion ?

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Film {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<String> Filmliste = new LinkedList<String>();
            }
    public void filmHinzufuegen(Film film) {
     if(!contains(film){
     Film.add (film);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Normally you are going to want to actually include the error that you are getting, so that others don't have to compile themselves to see it, but luckily this case is rather obvious... The filmHinzufuegen method does not have access to the LinkedList because it is declared locally within the main method. Also, `.contains()` method is part of list interface, so you need to call it *on* the list, instead of just calling `!contains(film)` (unless you plan on having your own contains method that itself calls it on the list, but it wasn't included so I'm assuming that's not the case.)

Comment: How is the `films` list declared and why are you not using it in your code?